# Hyphenation tables not working

Tags: hyphenation, plain-tex

Consider scratch.tex:

```
\language0
\hyphenation{ab-cdef}

\newlanguage\newlang
\newlang
\hyphenation{abc-def}

\language0
\showhyphens{abcdef}

\newlang
\showhyphens{abcdef}
```

Why in both cases hyphenation is `abc-def`?

**EDIT:**
The log shows `\newlang=\language1`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `\newlanguage\newlang`, TeX looks at the number of the most recently allocated language, steps it and assigns this number as the meaning of `\newlang`.

In your case, where you seem to be using Knuth TeX with the Plain format, the only allocated language is number 0, so the instruction `\newlanguage\newlang` prints in the `.log` file the information

```
\newlang=\language1
```

This might be misleading, because `\newlang` is *not* an instruction to change language (in the sense of hyphenation patterns and exceptions); actually, the internal instruction executed by TeX is

```
\chardef\newlang=1
```

and you have to say

```
\language\newlang
```

in order to activate the hyphenation patterns/exceptions for language 1. Running TeX on your example will print a Delta (which happens to be the character in slot 1 in `cmr10`).

Why did Knuth decide so, instead of defining `\newlanguage\newlang` so that `\newlang` becomes the full instruction to change language? There are some reasons for this:

1. you can compare two languages by number, like

   ```
   \ifnum\language=\newlang
     <current language is \newlang>
   \else
     <current language is not \newlang>
   \fi
   ```

   (note that in this context `\language` will return the number of the current language);
2. in some cases, `\setlanguage` must be used (see the end of Appendix H in the TeXbook).

We see that a symbolic token representing the number is necessary anyway; the situation is similar to that of box registers: when you say `\newbox\mybox`, you can't use `\mybox` by itself, but only after `\setbox` or `\box` or similar commands. Also in this case the `.log` file will have something like `\mybox=\box16` just for recording the allocated number, but this does not mean that you can use `\mybox` as a substitute for `\box16`.

Using

```
\language\newlang
```

instead of just `\newlang` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
\language0
\hyphenation{ab-cdef}

\newlanguage\newlang
\language\newlang
\hyphenation{abc-def}

\language0
\showhyphens{abcdef}

\language\newlang
\showhyphens{abcdef}
\bye
```

Comment: See update in the question.